# Can QGIS open folder with "run feature action" tool?

Tags: qgis, actions

Is possible to open folder with "run feature action" tool? I can open specific file like .dwg, but don`t know how open folder in specific location. This folder contain multiple .dwg files and when user click this action, folder open in another window.

Is this possible in QGIS 1.8.0, and how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On windows, the following works for me:

```
explorer C:\Users\Anita\Geodaten\[% "myattribute" %]
```

Just add whichever field contains the folder name.